# Android : Shared Preferences unable to Store Value in Shared Preferences

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-sharedpreferences

I am currently working in a project where i have to update shared preferences depending on the widget pressed, if user presses  widget Shared preferences will store "OFF" other wise "ON".

On the Other Side ,the same code of  Shared Preferences are storing their values in Activities and Services but not working with Widgets

Following is my code Snippet:

The **Widget.class**

```
  @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onReceive(context, intent);
        Toast.makeText(context,"Clicked",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        if (SYNC_CLICKED.equals(intent.getAction())) {

            AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);

            RemoteViews remoteViews;
            ComponentName watchWidget;

            remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.activity_main3);
            watchWidget = new ComponentName(context, Main3Activity.class);
            SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences("Settings", 0);

            //battey_stats =mpref.getString("on_off", "15");
            Toast.makeText(context,app,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            if(app.equals("OFF"))
            {
                app="ON";
                SharedPreferences set =context. getSharedPreferences("Settings", 0); // 0 - for private mode
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = set.edit();
                editor.putString("on_off", "OFF");
                editor.commit();
                remoteViews.setImageViewResource(R.id.button, R.drawable.unchecked_box);


                }

            else
            {
                Toast.makeText(context,"ONN",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
               app="OFF";
                SharedPreferences set =context. getSharedPreferences("Settings", 0); // 0 - for private mode
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = set.edit();
                editor.putString("on_off", "OFF");
                editor.commit();
                remoteViews.setImageViewResource(R.id.button, R.drawable.icon);
            }
           // remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.button, "TESTING");
            appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(watchWidget, remoteViews);


        }
    }
```

When i click on widget Images are changing ***if and else block works perfectly***  but ***Shared Preferences*** doesn't store the values Plus the same code of ***Shared Preferences*** is working in ***Services*** and ***Activites***

Answer (score 0):

use `settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);`

this method works for all services, activities, widgets, etc.

Comment: Because your variant namely depends on class where preferences are used

Comment: I mean if you wanna share setting for all app use what I wrote